# How to align Gridview headers to right ?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, gridview

i am trying to align Headers of gridview to RIGHT but it doesn't work, i even tried center etc but none of them works but it works on item. I want to align HEADER of columns CR,DR to right, help please, i saw many articles but didn't help.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewLedger" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                ShowFooter="True" DataKeyNames="AccountID"
                CssClass="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered">
                <Columns>
                    <%-- <asp:BoundField HeaderText="TransactionID" DataField="TransactionID" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop"
                                HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Account ID" DataField="Account_ID" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop"
                                HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop" />--%>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Account Title" DataField="AccountTitle" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop"
                        HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop">
                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="visible-desktop"></HeaderStyle>

                        <ItemStyle Width="11%" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Voucher No" DataField="VoucherNumber" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop"
                        HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop">
                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="visible-desktop"></HeaderStyle>

                        <ItemStyle Width="8%"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Chq No" DataField="ChequeNumber" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop"
                        HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop">
                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="visible-desktop"></HeaderStyle>

                        <ItemStyle Width="8%" CssClass="visible-desktop"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="DateTime" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MMM/yyyy hh:mm}" HtmlEncode="false"  DataField="TransactionDateTime" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop"
                        HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop">
                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="visible-desktop"></HeaderStyle>

                        <ItemStyle Width="13%" CssClass="visible-desktop"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="InvoiceNo" DataField="InvoiceNo" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop"
                        HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop">
                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="visible-desktop"></HeaderStyle>

                        <ItemStyle Width="3%" CssClass="visible-desktop" ></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Particulars" DataField="Particulars" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop"
                        HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop">
                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="visible-desktop"></HeaderStyle>

                        <ItemStyle CssClass="visible-desktop" Width="30%"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="DR" DataField="DR" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop"
                        HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop">
                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="visible-desktop" HorizontalAlign="Right"></HeaderStyle>

                        <ItemStyle CssClass="visible-desktop" Width="8%" HorizontalAlign="Right"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="CR" DataField="CR" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop"
                        HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop">
                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="visible-desktop" HorizontalAlign="Right"></HeaderStyle>

                        <ItemStyle CssClass="visible-desktop" HorizontalAlign="Right"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Amount" DataField="Amount" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop"
                        HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop">
                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="visible-desktop"></HeaderStyle>

                        <ItemStyle CssClass="visible-desktop"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <%--<asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop" HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop" />--%>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your GridView

```
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridHeaderAlignRight" />
</asp:GridView>
```

In your CSS File

```
.gridHeaderAlignRight {
    text-align:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code here is correct

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="DR" DataField="DR" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop" HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-desktop">
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="visible-desktop" HorizontalAlign="Right"></HeaderStyle>
    <ItemStyle CssClass="visible-desktop" Width="8%" HorizontalAlign="Right"></ItemStyle>
</asp:BoundField>
```

I suspect this class `visible-desktop` or another is the cause of `HorizontalAlign="Right"` not working. So investigate it in FireBug (or equivalent).